# Does my method to construct a step function correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Here is my homework.
$f\in L([a,b]),\epsilon>0$.Prove that exist a step function $S(x)$ such that 
$$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-S(x)|dx<\epsilon$$
My method:

Assume that $f$ is non-negative, or we will discuss $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$ of $f$.

Since we can find a continuous function $h(x)$ s.t.
$$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-h(x)|dx<\epsilon$$
So,we just need to find $S(x)$,s.t.
$$\int_{a}^{b}|S(x)-h(x)|dx<\epsilon$$
Obviously,$h(x)$ is Riemann integral,for the $\epsilon$ above, there exist a partition of $[a,b]$$\, a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n = b\,$,$\exists\xi_{i}\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$,s.t.
$$|\int_{a}^{b}h(x)dx-\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})|<\epsilon$$
That is
$$\int_{a}^{b}|h(x)-\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})|dx<\epsilon$$
Then we find the step function $S(x)$
$$S(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(\xi_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$
At the interval $(x_{i-1},x_i)$,we have find a constant $\frac{h(\xi_{i})}{b-a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand a bit what you've done.  We have that

$|\int_{a}^b h(x) dx = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} h(\xi_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})| < \epsilon$.

By noting that $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^b dx = 1$, we can move the sum underneath the integral and see that

$|\int_{a}^b h(x) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} h(\xi_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})dx| < \epsilon$.

This isn't quite the same as what you have.  You can't move the absolute value underneath the integral.  However, the following two devices will allow for this:

1) We may assume h is nonnegative (why?)

2) We may approximate h from below (why?)

Comment: Yeah,I should point out that $h(x)$ should  be nonnegative,but why do we need to approximate h from below ?

Comment: Sorry, in this case it's above.  What you're trying to show is that there's a step function $S(x)$ which satisfies

$\int_{a}^b |S(x) - h(x)| dx \le \epsilon$.  What you have so far is that 

$|\int_a^b S(x) - h(x) dx| \le \epsilon$.  However, these are not the same thing.  If additionally $h(x) \le S(x)$, then $\int_a^b S(x) - h(x) dx = \int_a^b |S(x) - h(x)| dx$, because $S - h \ge 0$.

You should also be careful about your usage of two different integrals here.  You're using a Riemann integral to approximate h and a Lebesgue integral (I assume) for f.  Do you know that these are the same?

Comment: You're right. I use the inf finally.